# How to remove the number in "Heading 1" - officeR

Tags: r, officer

Is it possible to remove the number when I add a heading in a word document?

```
my_doc <- read_docx() %>% 
body_add_par("This is a heading", style = "heading 1")
print(my_doc, target = 'dummy.docx')
```

The result in word is **1. This is a heading**

But I would like to have without the number: **This is a heading**

Comment: Tried to reproduce your code but I got: Error in is.character(path) : argument "path" is missing, with no default. Is the docxtractr library you used for the read_docx function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`officer` uses styles from so called 'initial document' (or 'template')

When you call `read_docx` with unspecified `path` argument, empty document located in the package directory is used as intial file. So go there and edit Heading 1 style.